# Error Rendering View [.xhtml]

Tags: jsf, jboss, illegalargumentexception

I am having this problem with JBoss server. The application is deployed on JBoss server 4.3. I can start the server and access the application but when I click on any of the links in the dropdown menu it gives me the following error:

```
11:34:56,229 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:34:56,229 INFO  [PrettyFilter] Forwarding mapped request [/enq/mail/new] to JSF viewId [/idms/enquiry-mail-new.jsf]
11:34:56,744 ERROR [viewhandler] Error Rendering View[/idms/enquiry-mail-new.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number 0''
at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1339)
at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:458)
at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:350)
at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:811)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createValidator(ApplicationImpl.java:904)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ValidateDelegateHandler.createValidator(ValidateDelegateHandler.java:51)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidateHandler.apply(ValidateHandler.java:90)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:337)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:307)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:337)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:307)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Here is my source file:

```
<ui:param name="pageTitle" value="#{idmsBundle.PageTitle_enquiryMailNewSearch}" />
<ui:param name="breadcrumbsNodeId" value="idmsEnquiryMailNewSearch" />
<ui:param name="breadcrumbsNodeLabel" value="#{idmsBundle.BreadCrumb_enquiryMailNewSearch}" />
<ui:param name="workflowBean" value="#{idmsEnquiryMailNewSearch_backing}" />
<ui:param name="idxLink" value="#{idmsBundle.Link_index}" />

<ui:define name="style">
    <style type="text/css">
        .criteria-height                        { height: 130px }
        label#criteriaForm\3a workqueueLabel    { width: 95px; }
        label#criteriaForm\3a branchLabel   { width: 85px;  }
        label#criteriaForm\3a ariesLabel    { width: 100px;  }
        label#criteriaForm\3a claimsLabel   { width: 85px;  }
        label#criteriaForm\3a chequeLabel   { width: 95px; }
        label#criteriaForm\3a paymentLabel  { width: 85px; }
        label#criteriaForm\3a currencyLabel { width: 85px; }
        label#criteriaForm\3a docIdLabel        { width: 75px; }
        label#criteriaForm\3a indateLabel       { width: 155px; }
        label#criteriaForm\3a valuedateLabel    { width: 85px; }

        #criteriaForm\3a branchInputHolder      { width: 100px; }
        #criteriaForm\3a branchInput            { width: 50px; }
        #criteriaForm\3a ariesInput             { width: 150px; text-transform: uppercase;}
        #criteriaForm\3a claimsInput            { width: 100px; text-transform: uppercase; }
        #criteriaForm\3a chequeInput            { width: 100px; text-transform: uppercase;}
        #criteriaForm\3a paymentInput           { width: 120px; }
        #criteriaForm\3a currencyInput          { width: 40px; text-transform: uppercase;}
        #criteriaForm\3a docIdInput         { width: 100px; }
        #criteriaForm\3a valuedateInput         { width: 110px; }
    </style>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="searchCriteria">
    <h:outputLabel id="branchLabel" for="branchInput" value="* #{appBundle.FormLabel_branchCode}"/>
    <h:panelGroup id="branchInputHolder" styleClass="form-input">
        <h:inputText id="branchInput" label="#{appBundle.Label_branchCode}"
                value="#{workflowBean.message.branch}"
                maxlength="4" required="true" converter="aoc2kBranchConverter">
        </h:inputText>
        <kl:suggestionboxTrigger id="branchSbTrigger" for="criteriaForm:branchSuggestion"/>
        <kl:message for="branchInput"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="ariesLabelId">
        <h:outputLabel id="ariesLabel" for="ariesInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_ariesref}"/>
        <h:inputText id="ariesInput" label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_ariesref}" value="#{workflowBean.message.ariesRef}" maxlength="20" styleClass="form-input" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <br/>
    <h:panelGroup id="claimsLabelId">
        <h:outputLabel id="claimsLabel" for="claimsInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_claimsref}"  />
        <h:inputText id="claimsInput" label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_claimsref}" value="#{workflowBean.message.claimsRef}" maxlength="12" styleClass="form-input" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="chequeLabelId">
        <h:outputLabel id="chequeLabel" for="chequeInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_chequeno}"/>
        <h:inputText id="chequeInput" label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_chequeno}" value="#{workflowBean.message.chequeNo}" maxlength="12" styleClass="form-input" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <br/>

    <h:panelGroup id="paymentLabelId">
        <h:outputLabel id="paymentLabel" for="paymentInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_paymentamt}"/>
        <h:inputText id="paymentInput" label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_paymentamt}" value="#{workflowBean.message.paymentAmount}" maxlength="19" styleClass="form-input"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputLabel id="docIdLabel" for="docIdInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_docid}"/>
    <h:inputText id="docIdInput" label="#{idmsBundle.Label_docid}" value="#{workflowBean.message.docId}" 
        maxlength="9" styleClass="form-input"/>

    <br/>

    <h:panelGroup id="currencyLabelId">
        <h:outputLabel id="currencyLabel" for="currencyInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_currency}"/>
        <h:inputText id="currencyInput"  label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_currency}" value="#{workflowBean.message.currency}" maxlength="3" styleClass="form-input" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputLabel id="indateLabel" for="indateInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_indatetime}" />
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="form-input">
        <rich:calendar id="indateInput" inputSize="10" enableManualInput="true" showWeeksBar="false"
            value="#{workflowBean.message.auditTrail.createdTime}"
            datePattern="#{idmsBundle.DateInputFormat}" label="#{idmsBundle.Label_indatetime}"
            converterMessage="#{idmsMsgBundle['idms.converter.INVALID_INDATE_DATEFORMAT']}">
                <f:validator validatorId="validateDate" />
        </rich:calendar>
        <kl:message for="indateInput"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <br/>

    <h:outputLabel id="valuedateLabel" for="valuedateInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_valuedate}" />
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="form-input" >
                <rich:calendar id="valuedateInput" inputSize="10" enableManualInput="true" showWeeksBar="false"
                    value="#{workflowBean.message.valueDate}"
                    required="false" datePattern="#{idmsBundle.DateFormat}" label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_valuedate}"
                    converterMessage="#{idmsBundle.converterMessage_valuedate}">
                        <f:validator validatorId="validateDate" />
                </rich:calendar>
                <kl:message for="valuedateInput" />

    </h:panelGroup>

     <!-- Autocomplete, make sure resetCmd reRender this component or will result JS error -->
    <kl:branchAutocomplete id="branchSuggestion" for="branchInput">
        <a4j:actionparam name="funcd" value="#{applicationContextBean.currentUserFunctionCode}"/>
    </kl:branchAutocomplete>

    <a4j:keepAlive beanName="idmsEnquiryMailNewSearch_backing" />

</ui:define>

<ui:param name="resultColumnsWidth" value="90px,100px,50px,70px,140px,90px,50px,50px,70px,70px" />
<ui:define name="resultColumns">

    <rich:column  sortBy="#{item.row.claimsRef}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_claimsref}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.row.claimsRef}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column  sortBy="#{item.row.paymentAmount}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_paymentamt}" />
        </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.row.paymentAmount}" style="float : right;" >
                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" />
                </h:outputText>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column  sortBy="#{item.row.currency}" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_ccy}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.row.currency}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column sortBy="#{item.row.valuedate}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_valuedate}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.row.valueDate}">
            <kl:convertDateTime pattern="#{idmsBundle.DateFormat}"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortBy="#{item.row.ariesRef}" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_ariesref}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.row.ariesRef}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column  sortBy="#{item.row.chequeNo}" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_chequeno}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.row.chequeNo}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column sortBy="#{item.row.fileOnly}" style="text-align: center;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_filing}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/tick.png" rendered="#{item.row.fileOnly}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortBy="#{item.row.priority}" style="text-align: center;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_urgent}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/tick.png" rendered="#{item.row.priority}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortBy="#{item.row.auditTrail.createdBy}" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_inuserid}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.row.auditTrail.createdBy}"/>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortBy="#{item.row.docId}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{idmsBundle.Label_docid}"  />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.row.docId}"/>
    </rich:column>
</ui:define>
```

I have a feeling it is a problem with the JSF but not quite sure on what it is. I would be really grateful if someone could help. Thanks!

Okay I have isolated the problem but still I do not know how to solve it. The problem comes in this part of the code:

```
 <h:outputLabel id="indateLabel" for="indateInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_indatetime}" />
<h:panelGroup styleClass="form-input">
    <rich:calendar id="indateInput" inputSize="10" enableManualInput="true" showWeeksBar="false"
        value="#{workflowBean.message.auditTrail.createdTime}"
        datePattern="#{idmsBundle.DateInputFormat}" label="#{idmsBundle.Label_indatetime}"
        converterMessage="#{idmsMsgBundle['idms.converter.INVALID_INDATE_DATEFORMAT']}">
            <f:validator validatorId="validateDate" />
    </rich:calendar>
    <kl:message for="indateInput"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<br/>

<h:outputLabel id="valuedateLabel" for="valuedateInput" value="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_valuedate}" />
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="form-input" >
            <rich:calendar id="valuedateInput" inputSize="10" enableManualInput="true" showWeeksBar="false"
                value="#{workflowBean.message.valueDate}"
                required="false" datePattern="#{idmsBundle.DateFormat}" label="#{idmsBundle.FormLabel_valuedate}"
                converterMessage="#{idmsBundle.converterMessage_valuedate}">
                    <f:validator validatorId="validateDate" />
            </rich:calendar>
            <kl:message for="valuedateInput" />

</h:panelGroup>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like something is missing inside a message format, probably an <h:outputFormat /> with missing parameter. The file in cause looks to be /idms/enquiry-mail-new.jsf, can you post source of this file?

Comment: The only thing I see, maybe this can't be found : converterMessage="#{idmsMsgBundle['idms.converter.INVALID_INDATE_DATEFORMAT']}"

Comment: You should try to isolate this issue (remove columns / inputTexts) and then post this (short as possible) code fragment. And I'm sure, that your CSS `width` settings are not related to this problem.

Comment: Hi I think I figured out the problem but I am not sure how to solve it. While debugging I was tracking the MessageFormat.class and I found it was trying to parse ''{0''} and that is where the problem was coming. Other instances parsed ''{0}'' and there was no problem in that, so I think that this is just a typing error. But I cannot find where is this argument coming from. The code does not go through the only place where the method is explicitly called, so I am really confused how this method is being called. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey I have isolated the problem. Any suggestions now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve the issue with the help of a friend. Apparently I had a jsf-impl.jar in my `server\default\lib` which was giving me the error. Thanks everyone for your help.